# MySQL - Rounding (sort of) - Want to round number only if greater than/less than 10

Tags: mysql, rounding, ceil

My query looks like this:

```
SELECT id, name, 
MATCH (name) AGAINST (%serach term%) as relevance,
address 
FROM table
```

I'm getting relevance results ranging betweeen 5.1 and 14.0.  I want to sort by relevance, but also by another field, so I'd like to round the relevance a bit.

I got something working like this:

```
SELECT id, name, 
round(MATCH (name) AGAINST (%serach term%),0) as relevance,
address 
FROM table
```

This rounds it to the nearest whole number.

But, ideally, I'd really like to know which are above 10 and which are below 10 and have that be the only distinguishing factor.

So:  1, 5.1, 9.9 would all 'round' to 10.
Then, 10.1, 14.1, would all 'round' to 20.

Or it could be 0 and 1.  Or 0 and 10, or 0 and 20.

I'm not sure how to go about this, or if it's even possible.  I've been looking at ceiling() and round() but I can't quite figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try CASE WHEN

```
SELECT id, name, 
CASE WHEN MATCH (name) AGAINST (%serach term%) <= 10 THEN 10 
     WHEN MATCH (name) AGAINST (%serach term%) > 10 THEN 20
     END as relevance,
address 
FROM table
```

Comment: This seems to work, thanks.  I'm wondering though - do you think this does 2x the work matching?  Would there be a performance loss here on a query across a large database?

Comment: The MySQL optimizer should only execute the match once, but I'm honestly not familiar enough with MyISAM any more to say 100% for sure. You have a full text index on name, right? Do you mind testing and sharing what you find? I haven't used MyISAM is so long, I'm not sure (although I would expect it to perform the match only once)

Comment: I really expect this would be handled by caching actually... do you mind putting EXPLAIN EXTENDED in front of your query (both with and without the case when on the match). Also, you have enabled your slow query log, yes?

Comment: Yes, it's a fulltextindex on name.  I'll to an EXPLAIN and reply back.

Comment: I ran EXPLAIN EXTENDED against my original query and the one modified for CASE WHEN and they yielded the exact same results, so you were correct.  Thanks!